# Linux kernel patches: can I skip some?

Tags: linux, kernel, patch

I have the source of Linux 3.4.0 to which I added some modifications. I know that here (ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/) I can find all the 107 patches that need to be applied to my source to update it to the 3.4.107 version.

I read that I have to apply them one by one: first the 3.4.1, then the 3.4.2, then the 3.4.3 etc.

But my doubt is: can I apply directly the 3.4.107 patch?

I opened the 3.4.107 patch file and noticed that it changes SUBLEVEL = 0 in Makefile to SUBLEVEL = 107, so I thought that this means that it is meant to be used by devs who still have got the 3.4.0 source. What's more, I also noticed that the size of the patch files increases from 3.4.1 to 3.4.107, this seems to confirm my idea that every patch contains:

- all the changes that are included in the previous patches
- its new fixes.

Can you tell me whether I'm right or not?

Comment: Why not just do a `make oldconf`?

Comment: I have 3.4.0 source and I want to update it to 3.4.107 with patches (I've seen many devs doing this). This is why I asked my question.

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you're modifying it, use a git clone instead. That should make your life much easier in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each patch in https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ applies to the first release of the corresponding series, so you should apply https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/patch-3.4.107.xz directly to your 3.4.0 source tree. Incremental patches are available, but they're stored separately, in https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/incr/; you would use these to patch an already-patched tree (*e.g.* if you want to upgrade your 3.4.107 tree to a future 3.4.108).

As [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) suggests, you'll find keeping up with kernel changes much easier if you work in a copy of the corresponding `git` stable repository; that will allow you to rebase your patches onto new releases as they come, and benefit from the merge tools available in that context.